# ionic apk dont show Splash Screens

Tags: cordova, apk, ionic-framework, splash-screen, screens

I'm building an application based on the WordPress blog using ionic. I added Splash Screens and switched it on my device but it's not working. i took The apk file from ant-build folder but when I run it on the machine does not show me anything. Is not closed right file? The settings in xml or incorrect?

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myappe2785d518e9f4f6ea03055878dd7a400" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="en-US">
        <name>kikarNews</name>
        <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
        <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <vs:features />
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
      <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
        <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
        <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
        <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true|false" />
        <platform name="android">
          <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
          <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
          <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
          <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
          <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
          <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
          <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
          <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
          <!-- iPad -->
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
          <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
          <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
          <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
          <!-- iPad -->
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
          <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
          <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
          <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="windows">
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="" height="" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
          <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="wp8">
          <icon src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="62" height="62" />
          <icon src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="173" height="173" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="android">
          <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
          <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
          <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
          <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
          <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
          <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
          <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
          <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
          <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="windows">
          <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300" />
          <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
          <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="wp8">
          <splash src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.jpg" width="480" height="800" />
        </platform>
        <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" version="0.2.12" />
        <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.3.0" />
        <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.3.0" />
        <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="1.0.0" />
      </widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the method that you used for generating splash screens.I have used ionic CLI.

By using this method,you can generate splash screens automatically  from source images to create each size needed for each platform.There is no need of copying each resized and cropped image into each platform's resources directory.

Save a **splash.png, splash.psd or splash.ai** file within the resources directory at the root of the Cordova project. The source image's minimum dimensions should be **2208x2208 px**.Additionally, when the Orientation preference config is set to either landscape or portrait mode, then only the necessary images will be generated.

```
$ ionic resources --splash
```

[Refer](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html)